# Removing fields from category/taxonomy edit form

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-admin

Terms like 'slug' and 'description' on custom taxonomy edit pages tend to mislead my client. Is there a way of removing these from the page flow? At the moment I'm using JavaScript, which isn't ideal. I was looking at `{$taxonomy}_pre_edit_form` and its ilk, but none of them seemed to offer the fields for editing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source (edit-tag-form.php) it doesn't look like there is a way of doing this through filters, as the code is directly outputted as oposed to being held in a variable. All `{$taxonomy}_pre_edit_form` does is allow you to add code before the form.

JS I think is the only way, and to be honest it's not a bad way - it sould only be a few odd lines, and if it achieves what you want, then it's surely good news.

Comment: you're probably right. a second opinion is always nice :)

Comment: Always a shame when you can't do what you want. Maybe mention it as an improvement on Trac - it would be easy enough to do.